# How to temporary disable cpanel/WordPress mailing abilities

Tags: wordpress, email, cpanel

Quick question since i'm in a rush, my WordPress install has been hacked and is spamming how can i temporary disable the sites mailing abilities while i look for the malicious code.

Comment: You can't stop mail send form your site. Hack, usually use a script (injection) and use mail() php function. It's question of Hosting or SysAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bet is to contact your hosting company.

This resource is helpful if you want to try to solve it yourself: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Prevent+Email+Abuse#HowtoPreventEmailAbuse-Overview